# Bad numerical reference in XML

Tags: java, xml

I have the XML file wich contains numeric reference:

```
<tag>
    Some text:&#0011;
</tag>
```

This XML file is non valid (nor IE and Chrome could not open it), cause char with code 11 is not valid for XML. When I try to validate xml vs xsd this verification failed with exception. If I change this reference to `&#0010;` the file becomes valid.

So I want to fix source file by replacing all incorrect references by spaces. Is there any way in Java to determine which reference is correct?

Comment: @Tichodroma Actually, this is a vertical tab. The character entity is *not* hexadecimal but decimal. So it is the same as `&#x000b;`. A vertical tab is not that far-fetched in a document, but alas, it's invalid in XML.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Stupid me :)

Comment: Besides the [vertical tab](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm) what other entities are in the XML fileß

Answer (score 0):

This character is valid in XML 1.1, so you could find an XSLT/XML processor combination that supports XML 1.1 (e.g Saxon+Apache Xerces), and deal with the offending characters in XSLT. It can be done with an identity transform and a character map.